# Nested JavaFX Controller inside public class

Tags: java, javafx

I have the code below which contains a class and a nested `JavaFX Controller`.I initialize the JavaFX Controller class and i get an instance of it like you can see.

**SpeechWindow class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import application.Main;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * SpeechWindow
 *
 */
public class SpeechWindow extends Stage {

    private Container container = new Container();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public SpeechWindow() {

        setTitle("SpeechResults");
        setScene(new Scene(container));
    }

    /**
     * @param text
     */
    public void appendText(String text) {
        container.appendText(text);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void clear() {
        container.clear();
    }

    public class Container extends BorderPane implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private TextArea textArea;

        public Container() {
            // FXMLLOADER
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SpeechWindow.fxml"));
            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location , ResourceBundle resources) {
            System.out.println("Container has been initialized..");
        }

        public void appendText(String text) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText(text + "\n"));
        }

        public void clear() {
            Platform.runLater(textArea::clear);
        }

    }

}
```

Here it is the **FXML code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <TextArea fx:id="textArea" editable="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="...no response" wrapText="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

---

Try to call it from the Main JavaFX Application class creating an instance of `SpeechWindow` and call `appendText();` method.A null pointer comes out why?

**The goal is:**

Then i want to create an instance the outer class and use it.

---

**What goes wrong:**

If i create an instance of `SpeechWindow` class and call the method `appendText();` i get null pointer exception...Why that happens,i see everything done fine.What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never connect the controller instance to the fxml.

Use `setController` for the `FXMLLoader` to set the controller class.

Furthermore you need to add the result of loading the fxml to the scene somehow. Probably you should replace the root element of the fxml with a `fx:root` element.

BTW: It seems like a bad idea to simply catch a load an exception, if the instance cannot be used, if such a exception happens...

```
public Container() {
    // FXMLLOADER
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SpeechWindow.fxml"));

    // set controller & root
    loader.setController(this);
    loader.setRoot(this);
    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // throw as cause of RuntimeException
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <TextArea fx:id="textArea" editable="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="...no response" wrapText="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: Oh daaaamn how i missed that ,thanks Fabian ! I will check if it works and then mark it as answer...

Answer (score 1):

You must use [FXMLLoader.getController()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController--) method to obtain your `Container` class before calling its methods.

Try to call

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(".../SpeechWindow.fxml"));
```

from `SpeechWindow` class instead of `Container`'s constructor. Then retreive the `Container` class by

```
Container container = loader.getController();
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Cryptor but here i want to use `fx:root`,i missed something that you can see in Fabian's answer.

Comment: Anyway this answer shouldn't work since there is no controller created by the `FXMLLoader`, since there is not `fx:controller` attribute specified in the fxml...